# How to Print innertext during Parsing with Simple HTML dom parser

Tags: php, parsing

I want Print innertext during Parsing with Simple HTML dom parser

HTML Source Code:

```
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_Middle_RatingSummary1_Rating1_RatingPanel">
<img id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_Middle_RatingSummary1_Rating1_RatingImage" title="(2.5 / 5)  : Above Average" src="../../../../../images/net/common/stars/transparent/2.5.png" alt="(2.5 / 5)  : Above Average" style="border-width:0px;" />
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_Middle_RatingSummary1_Rating1_RatingText" class="text med strong">(2.5 / 5)  : Above Average</span>
<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_Middle_RatingSummary1_Rating1_RatingHelp" class="help"></a>
```

I want Output like this:

```
(2.5 / 5)  : Above Average
```

I tried it, but not Getting it:

Php code:

```
$ratings = $html->find('div[id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_Middle_RatingSummary1_Rating1_RatingPanel] span')->outertext;

echo "$ratings[0]";
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = $file_get_contents('myfile.html');
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$a = dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach($a as $tags)
{
$attr = $tags->getAttribute('title');
echo $attr
}
```

or may be try directly based on your html input:

```
$attr = dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->getAttribute('title');
echo $attr
```

Comment: Getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

Comment: @user2689656 check now.